# kv_do() not working as expected

Tags: g-wan

This is in my **init.c**:

```
server_data_t **data = (server_data_t**)get_env(argv, US_SERVER_DATA);
data[0] = (server_data_t*)calloc(1, sizeof(server_data_t));

kv_t *channels = &data[0]->channels;
kv_t *users = &data[0]->users;

kv_init(channels, "channels.dat", 10*1024, 0, 0, 0);
kv_init(users, "users.dat", 10*1024, 0, 0, 0);
```

These initializations were only for testing puproses:

```
channel_t *channel = (channel_t*)calloc(1, sizeof(channel_t));
channel->name = strdup("Test channel");
channel->id = 1;

kv_item channel_item;
channel_item.key = (char*)&channel->id;
channel_item.klen = sizeof(u32);
channel_item.val = (char*)channel;
channel_item.in_use = 0;

kv_add(channels, &channel_item);

channel_t *channel2 = (channel_t*)calloc(1, sizeof(channel_t));
channel2->name = strdup("Test channel2");
channel2->id = 2;

kv_item channel_item2;
channel_item2.key = (char*)&channel2->id;
channel_item2.klen = sizeof(u32);
channel_item2.val = (char*)channel2;
channel_item2.in_use = 0;

kv_add(channels, &channel_item2);

kv_do(channels, NULL, sizeof(u32), test_proc, 0);
```

The user defined process kv_do process:

```
static int test_proc(const kv_item *item, const void *ctx)
{
    return 1;
}
```

Starting the server segfaults after the kv_do test process starts an infinite loop when trying to visit all items. It works fine with one item in the list, then it just visits the first item and quits. I can also visit the items one by one with the ID using kv_get.

I found an edge case where it worked with two items if my key was "Test Channel" key length was strlen("Test Channel") and then the next channel key was "Test Channel2" where key-length was as long as the first items key-length. Pretty confusing.

Is the mistake in the code (pointers and such) or how the process is supposed to work with the return value of 1?

I know that gwan sometimes have trouble with KVMs so if it could be that, I'm running Oracle VM VirtualBox v5.0.24 with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Are the `kv.c` and `persistence.c` G-WAN examples working for you?

If any of them crashes, then you are probably using out-of-sync. G-WAN headers (`gwan.h`) with a recent `./gwan` executable.

Comment: I made a fresh install of debian8 instead of VM now and tested by downloading and installing the latest version of Gwan. kv.c crashes when using kv_do() -- persistence.c works. Commenting out the kv_do() routines makes kv.c run fine.

`Signal        : 11:Unknown SIGSEGV problem
Signal src    : 128:.
errno         : 0
Thread        : 1`